# HTTP request headers not being forwarded by Angular proxy

Tags: javascript, angular, proxy, http-post

I've set up `proxy.conf.json` to reroute requests from the development server on localhost to my API (which is already running in production). This is what I have:

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": API_URL,
    "secure": true,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": "/api/v1"
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

For example, `localhost:4200/api/get_token` should be rerouted to `API_URL/api/v1/get_token`.
The requests are rerouted correctly, but the headers aren't being forwarded. This is what the log says:

```
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/api/get_api_token" to "/api/v1/get_api_token"
[HPM] POST /api/get_api_token ~> API_URL
```

[image: Request headers from DevTools]

What should I do to solve this?